Decreasing the text granularity when working with image_to_boxes in `pytesseract`
I have the following image:

I tried image_to_boxes function to draw bounding boxes but the boxes are drawn around each letter. I am guessing that this is due to the large font of the text or the spacing between letters.
Is it possible to decrease granularity or something so that I can draw boxes around each word?
I also tried image_to_data, which does return bounding boxes for individual words but some words are missed, i.e. it isn't very accurate.
